# Where should I implement my check for collision method?

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a pokemon ripoff in pygame, and I have made a method to test whether the player is in the tall grass. However, I do not know where I should call the method. I have tried in the player move method, in the game loop method, and the update method. When I do it like this, it checks after you have moved out of the grass, which means the first time you move into grass it won't work, and when you first move out of grass it works (when it shouldn't).

`in_grass(self)` method:

```
def in_grass(self):
        for g in self.game.grass:
            if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, g):
                print(random.randint(1, 10000))
                if random.randint(1, 180) <= 25:
                    self.battle()
```

player `move(self)` method:

```
def move(self, x_change, y_change):
        if x_change > 0:
            self.dir = 'RIGHT'
        if x_change < 0:
            self.dir = 'LEFT'
        if y_change > 0:
            self.dir = 'DOWN'
        if y_change < 0:
            self.dir = 'UP'

        if not self.collide(x_change, y_change):
            self.x += x_change
            self.y += y_change

            image_list = None
            if self.dir == 'UP':
                image_list = self.image_up
            elif self.dir == 'LEFT':
                image_list = self.image_left
            elif self.dir == 'RIGHT':
                image_list = self.image_right
            elif self.dir == 'DOWN':
                image_list = self.image_down

            if image_list:
                if self.walkcount >= len(image_list):
                    self.walkcount = 0
                self.image = image_list[self.walkcount]
                self.walkcount += 1
                self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
```

Main loop:

```
 def events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    self.player.move(0, -1)
                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    self.player.move(-1, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    self.player.move(0, 1)
                if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    self.player.move(1, 0)

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                self.player.image = self.player.default_images[self.player.dir]
                self.player.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
```

EDIT: I finally got it working! I can't give myself the bounty, so I guess it will just sit there.

Comment: Quite honestly, it's up to you. You can put it anywhere you want, as long as it works. I prefer to put it directly after the move function in the mainloop. If this still does not work, try debugging your collision checker and strip it, and slowly add back lines of code until it stops working, allowing you to easily locate the source of the error

Comment: Agreed.  You need to do the "grass rustling" sound effect on move too.  Maybe it needs to do *something* in all these places.

Comment: Yeah, good idea. The problem is, I have tried multiple places and each movement is always one 'tile' behind. When I first move into grass, nothing happens. And when I do my next movement, it registers then and runs the `in_grass` function. I have tried it in multiple places, and for some reason it gets the same effect.

Comment: I don't know pygame very much, but is it possible that your coordinate change has not registered in the engine yet when you call `in_grass()`? Could you try and call `in_grass` directly after `self.x += x_change` and then debug into it to make sure the position of `self` in `collide_rect(self, g)` are the same as `self.x` right before?

Comment: In my head, it would need to be done before the player move animation.
So do a terrain check before the sprite moves. If the terrain the character is moving into is grass, then play "rustle" sound effect.  Then the character actually moves. It should happen so fast that it would be seamless.

Comment: @Cerno thanks, i've tried that and it still doesn't work. It is lagging behind by one.

Comment: @ChrisS, i've tried before `self.x += x_change`, and after, and it is still lagging behind by one. I really have no idea why it is doing that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a boolean in the player's `__init__` method callled `self.checked = False`. Then, in the `in_grass` method, at the end, set `self.checked = True`. In the `update` method, `if not self.checked: self.in_grass`. Finally in the `move` method, at the very start, set `self.checked = False`
I finally got it working, yay!

Comment: Good job figuring out a way to make this work. Would you like a more theoritical answer on where you would wanna do this in a bigger more complex game ?

Comment: @SamuelMiddendorp Yes please! I guess I can give you the bounty then lol

Comment: No need for that haha

Comment: Added and answer

Comment: If you want to hand it out, its up to you !

Answer (score 1):

So here is some food for thought.

Little disclaimer, 
I am in no way a game dev nor am i a very experienced developer.

In a larger game you might want to keep a good grasp on what is happening where. Now say we have a game full of entities (think of entities as things you see on screen that have some sort of impact on the game). We would wanna update all these entities every frame of the gameloop.

Entities might be rendered, moved, collission checked, affected by player input, animated or whatever functionality your game needs.
The order in which we do this is important for our game, suppose we have a list of entities

```py
entities = []
```

We could then do something like this where we loop trough each enemy in our gameloop en execute their behaviour function. we pass in all the entities into the check_collision function to make this code a little more understandable.

Version 1

```py
entities = []
def game_loop:
    while(true):
        for entity in entities:
            entity.gather_input()
            entity.move()
            entity.check_collision(entities)
            entity.animate()
            entity.render()
```

Now take a look at this:

Version 2

```py
entities = []
def game_loop:
    while(true):
        for entity in entities:
            entity.gather_input()
        for entity in entities:
            entity.move()
        for entity in entities:
            entity.check_collision(entities)
        for entity in entities:
            entity.animate()
        for entity in entities:
            entity.render()
```

The order in which we execute the entities their behaviour has changed. We now have grouped behaviour, we could say we have defined the update fases of our gameloop. We now know all the movement of entities is updated before we check all of their collisions.

Whereas in Version 1 we do all the logic first for 1 entity and then do the next. We might lose relevant data in a single frame using Version 1 because 1 entity might move and check collision wheres it really should've waited till all entities have moved.

Hope this might spark some more research into the rabbithole that is game design/architecture.